# Filter like API using query string in nodeJS and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filter

I'm trying to write a simple API using filter to get users from database. I want to filter this data by given specific params, which are optional:

How to make it flexible to get data from database by querying API with no params, single param and multiple params ?

Controller:-

**Method-1**

```
const articles = await userTable.find({
    '$or': [{
        'name': req.query.name
     },
     {
       'address': req.query.address
     },
     {
       'address': req.query.address,
       'name': req.query.name
     }]
  });
```

When I hit by single params it give correct response but when hit by multiple params http://localhost:4000/api/filter?name=abhishek&address=tejaji it give wrong response **but i want only that row which contains name abhishek and adress tejaji**

**Method-2**

```
const articles = await userTable.find({
    name:req.query.name,address:req.query.address,
    $or: [ { name:req.query.name }, {address:req.query.address } ]
});
```

When i hit by single params it give 0 response but when hit by multiple params http://localhost:4000/api/filter?name=abhishek&address=tejaji it give correct response **but i want result from single params also**

**Method-3**

```
const articles = await userTable.find({
  'usertables': {
        $elemMatch: {
          'name': req.query.name,
          'address': req.query.address
        }
    }
});
```

When i hit by single params [http://localhost:4000/api/filter?name=abhishek](http://localhost:4000/api/filter?name=abhishek&address=tejaji) or multiple http://localhost:4000/api/filter?name=abhishek&address=tejaji **it always give all rows from table**, which is wrong.

Route:-

```
router.get("/filter", userController.filterMethod);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use a `filter` object and add keys to it based on what params are present:

```
const { name, address } = req.query;
const filter = {}
if (name) {
    filter.name = name 
}
if (address) {
    filter.address = address
}
const articles = await userTable.find(filter);
```

Comment: You are a genius sir, thank you so much.
but i want to know apart from this solution, is there any other way ?